# Multiple camera panels per viewport layout, aka "Area"

Tags: 3d-view, interface, camera

I am struggling with what I believe to be a very simple task. I merely wish to view the framing of multiple cameras at the same time. It seems that it is not even possible to view the camera framing and a User Perspective view at the same time. This is shocking to me, I've been using 3D programs since 1991, and this is a new low in usability.

I am aware of the options "'n' > View > Local Camera" and "'n' > View > Lock Camera to View". These do not help me. The "Local Camera" only affects the top right panel. The backtick key to load the "pie menu" only affects the top right panel. It appears that Blender has extremely limited options for controlling the Quad viewport layout, and we can only change what appears in that top right panel.

The only workaround I have found is to copy the viewport "Area". From there I can choose whatever I want in that "Area". But it is a poor solution because 1) it duplicates all of the UI widgets (super cluttered) and 2) it limits my ability to go fullscreen. The new child "Area" is always visible.

I can also copy the viewport "Area" out to a floating window, which is better, but still, this is a poor solution to a problem that should not exist. I should be able to choose whatever I want in any of the four Quad panels, like in any other major DCC.

Please tell me that I am missing something and that there is a way to make Blender view more than one perspective view at the same time, in the same "Area".

Thanks

Aaron

Comment: Nothing ever limits your ability to go fullscreen, which is always available via the keyboard shortcut Ctrl + Spacebar. Though it is still the case that the Tool Shelf ("t") and the Properties Shelf ("n") will need to be collapsed manually using their respective hotkeys.

Comment: Also, you can create extra layouts at the top of the screen, using the "+" button next to the Workspace tabs. By creating a duplicate of one of the existing workspaces, you can then add windows for various editors, and this new arrangement will be unique to that workspace.

Comment: While it doesn't allow you to use camera views there is the hotkey ctrl+alt+q which splits the viewport into 4 different views.

Comment: Sorry, when I said "fullscreen" I meant for a single panel to take up the entire area of all panels. I did know about CTRL+SPACEBAR. The problem with that is that it takes up the entire UI, including Properties, etc.

I did know about CTRL+ALT+Q. It is extremely limited. The panels are all fixed to certain views, except the top right panel. I.e., I can't load a camera into the top right view and a User Perspective into the bottom right view, like in every other DCC I've ever seen.

I did know about creating workspaces. That is not a good solution, but apparently it is the only option.

Comment: I am expecting Blender to act like every other 3D DCC I've used (Maya, 3ds Max, Softimage) but it is decidedly very different. Window management is a super huge PITA. I'm in shock. The usability of this thing is amazingly poor. I can't even, say, open up a material editor window. I need to switch the entire workspace. This is an epic UI fail, a productivity nightmare. The UI paradigm of completely switching UI workspaces for different tasks went out of usage in 1995, but Blender is still using that paradigm. Horrifying.

Answer (score 1):

[image: VIEWING MULTIPLE CAMERA'S AT THE SAME TIME]

Hi Aaron,

If you have multiple camera's and some 3D viewports as shown in the picture. You can select a different camera in each viewport, by using the N key and then to the view tab, check the local camera and then choose the camera you want to use.

Best regards Gladys

Comment: Thanks Gladys, I know about this. It's a lot of work to create a separate "Area" for each camera. Then there's no way to maximize one "Area" to take up the same area as all four "Areas" combined. There's only CTRL+SPACEBAR to take over the entire interface, including all necessary panels in all "Areas". It's really dysfunctional compared to closed-source proprietary DCCs.